# Get Apex code through REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api

Is it possible get source code of Apex class/trigger through REST or any other APIs?

Comment: Yes it is.......Thats how the 3rd party IDE and tools do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do so with the **Tooling API**. Read more in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexclass.htm).

Also [here are some examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/01/new-in-spring-13-the-tooling-api.html) that show how to manipulate the object.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT Id
  ,Body
  ,Name
  ,NamespacePrefix
  ,Status 
FROM ApexClass
WHERE NamespacePrefix = NULL
```